# pandas: Replace string is not replacing targeted substring

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, pandas, replace

I am trying to iterate a list of strings using `dataframe1` to check whether the other `dataframe2` has any strings found in `dataframe1` to replace them.

```
for index, row in nlp_df.iterrows():
    print( row['x1'] )
    string1 = row['x1'].replace("(","\(")
    string1 = string1.replace(")","\)")
    string1 = string1.replace("[","\[")
    string1 = string1.replace("]","\]")
    nlp2_df['title'] = nlp2_df['title'].replace(string1,"")
```

In order to do this I iterated using the code shown above to check and replace for any string found in df1

The output belows shows the strings in df1

```
wait_timeout
interactive_timeout
pool_recycle
....
__all__
folder_name
re.compile('he(lo')
```

The output below shows the output after replacing strings in df2

```
0   have you tried watching the traffic between th...
1   /dev/cu.xxxxx is the "callout" device, it's wh...
2               You'll want the struct package.\r\r\n
```

For the output in `df2` strings like `/dev/cu.xxxxx` should have been replaced during the iteration but as shown it is not removed. However, I have attempted using `nlp2_df['title'] = nlp2_df['title'].replace("/dev/cu.xxxxx","")` and managed to remove it successfully.

Is there a reason why directly writing the string works but looping using a variable to use for replacing does not?

Answer (score 0):

IIUC you can simply use regular expressions:

```
nlp2_df['title'] = nlp2_df['title'].str.replace(r'([\(\)\[\]])',r'\\\1')
```

PS you don't need `for loop` at all...

Demo:

```
In [15]: df
Out[15]:
           title
0  aaa (bbb) ccc
1   A [word] ...

In [16]: df['new'] = df['title'].str.replace(r'([\(\)\[\]])',r'\\\1')

In [17]: df
Out[17]:
           title              new
0  aaa (bbb) ccc  aaa \(bbb\) ccc
1   A [word] ...   A \[word\] ...
```